# How to open a file in a specified program using window comand prompt

Tags: windows, terminal, command

How can I open a file from the command prompt in a specified program rather than the default program for opening the file.

like in MAC terminal

```
open main.js -a "Sublime Text"
```

currently I only do

```
start filename.extension
```

which opens the file in the default program.
please what command can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Windows, you type application first.

So with Notepad, which is on the Windows path, you can type

`notepad filename.extension`

By 'Windows Path' I mean a list of directories that Windows looks in for your application.  If your app is in one of those folders, then you only have to type the application name.  If your app isn't, then you need the full path to the application.

Most of the Windows native apps (like Notepad, MSPaint, etc) are automatically on the path.  However apps that are installed afterwards sometimes don't update the path and you need the full path.  You can usually get this by right-clicking on the application and getting properties.  Often you'll need quote marks - specifically if there are spaces in the path, which there usually are because "Program Files", so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" filename.extension
```

Note the quote marks go around the path to the application file itself - not all the way to the end of the line.  An easy way to check that you've got the full path to the file is with the dir command:

```
dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

Some applications expect instructions about what to do with the file, and you may need to figure out what else to put on the command line.  Usually google will tell you this.

For example, to execute an SQL script, with one tool I use, just putting the filename on the command line won't work, you do something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -U user -d dbName -f filename.extension
```